# Sending data from Iframe to parent works with Firefox but not with Safari: example included

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

I have a  with onclick="something" and a  wiht radio buttons and a  with onclick="something" inside the page shown in Iframe. I'm sending data to a parents  from the page inside an Iframe, but my code works with Firefox, but not with Safari. Any suggestions how to change the code to work with all browsers?

Here's the code (example from a bigger project)

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
function hello (string) { if (typeof string === 'object') {
for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
if (string[n].checked) {
string = string[n].value;
break;
}
}
}
var anchorText = document.getElementById('myAnchor').value;
if(anchorText !== '') {
anchorText += '\n';
}
anchorText += string;
document.getElementById('myAnchor').value = anchorText;
return false;
}
  </script>
  <title>joubadou</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>Cart<br>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="10" id="myAnchor"></textarea></form>
<iframe src="radiobuttontest.html" height="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And the page inside an Iframe

radiobuttontest.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
If you want a red car:<br>
<input value="add to cart" onclick="parent.hello('Red car')"
 type="button">
<br>
<br>
<form>If
you want a blue
car you can choose:<br>
  <input name="car" value="Bensin" checked="checked"
 type="radio">Bensin<br>
  <input name="car" value="Diesel" type="radio">Diesel<br>
  <input
 onclick="parent.hello('Blue car'); return parent.hello(document.getElementsByName('car'));"
 value="add to cart" type="button"></form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I have to change something in the code, or add something somewhere?

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: I have to figure this out. I don't know how to use this Web Storage, but I'm trying to learn...

Comment: you can visit link provided by me ....but its very easy to use..you just need to access object you can also try the solution and please accept and upvote answer if it helps you...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of HTML5 feature `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to pass data between parent and child iframe and eliminate all confusion, if `HTML5` is supported by browser version.

[Store data locally with HTML5 Web Storage](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2013/03/store-data-locally-with-html5-web.html)

Example :

```
 //localStorage
//set and get object 
localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');
var myVar = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
//another way to set and get
localStorage.myKey = 'myValue';
var myVar = localStorage.myKey;

//remove item   
localStorage.removeItem('myKey');

//clear storage
localStorage.clear();
```